# HQL query ignoring accents

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, diacritics

I've the following query:

```
select u from User u where upper(u.name) like upper(?1)
```

How this would be, but ignoring the accents in `u.name` and `?1`?

Comment: please elaborate your question... are you trying to remove accented chars from the comparison??

Comment: I want that accented characters, both the parameter and value in the database, to be ignored during the consultation.

Comment: I don't know if it can be done on the database side.  It should be doable on the Java side (remove accents before submitting your query), however I did not find anything relevant in the base libraries (java.util.text).  You would need to build a map of all accented characters with their corresponding "plain" character.  I'd be surprised that it has not been done already.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to implement this. Basically there are 2 steps:

1. normalize the parameter (in your case 1) and
2. normalize the data from the DB

*Example*

```
public User getByName(String paramName) {
   .....
}
```

Original HQL Query :

```
String queryString = "select u from User u where u.name : =paramName";
```

New Query:

```
paramName = normalizer(paramName );

String queryString = "select u from User u where " + replacer(u.name) +" : =paramName";
```

And the 2 methods:

```
public static String normalizer(String s)  {
    return Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
}

public String replacer(String param) {
    String t1 = "àâäçéèëêùûüôöïî";
    String t2 = "aaaceeeeuuuooii";
    String s = param;
    for (int i = 0; i < t1.length(); i++) {
        s = "replace(" + s + ",'" + t1.charAt(i) + "','" + t2.charAt(i) + "')";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? In most of them you can send a specific SQL command to set the collation.

Answer (score 0):

In portuguese, i missed the accents in some characters, so i added more characters in the replacer method:

```
public String replacer(String param) {
    String t1 = "áãàâäçéèëêùûüúóôöïîíÁÀÂÄÃÇÉÈËÊÙÛÜÚÓÔÖÏÎÍ";
    String t2 = "aaaaaceeeeuuuuoooiiiAAAAÃCEEEEUUUUOOOIII";
    String s = param;
    for (int i = 0; i < t1.length(); i++) {
        s = "replace(" + s + ",'" + t1.charAt(i) + "','" + t2.charAt(i) + "')";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With CriteriaBuilder you can use the following Specification

```
public static Specification<User> byNameIgnoringCaseAndAccents(String paramName) {

    return (root, cq, cb) -> {
        String paramNameNormalized = paramName != null ? normalize(paramName.toLowerCase()) : null;

        String characters = "áãàâäçéèëêùûüúóôöïîíÁÀÂÄÃÇÉÈËÊÙÛÜÚÓÔÖÏÎÍ";
        String replacements = "aaaaaceeeeuuuuoooiiiAAAAÃCEEEEUUUUOOOIII";
        Expression<String> replacedName = root.get("name");
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length(); i++) {
            replacedName = cb.function("REPLACE", String.class, replacedName, cb.literal(characters.charAt(i)), cb.literal(replacements.charAt(i)));
        }
        replacedName = cb.lower(replacedName);

        return cb.like(cb.literal(paramNameNormalized), cb.concat("%", cb.concat(replacedName, "%")));
    };
}

public static String normalize(String s) {
    return s != null ? Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "") : s;
}
```